# Complex integration in R

Tags: r, integrate

I'm trying to programming this function in R
Code Latex :

```
\int_R e^{iy}ydy, \textup{ }  , \textup{ }i^2=-1
```

I wrote this code :

```
i   = complex(real = 0, imaginary = 1)
```

`f=function(j){exp(i*t*j)*(j)}`

`integrate(f, lower = -Inf, upper = Inf)`

but I have this error :

> Error in integrate(f, lower = -Inf, upper = Inf) :    evaluation of
>   function gave a result of wrong type

Comment: `integrate` cannot do complex integration. Use `elliptic` package's `myintegrate` function.

Comment: I'v used : myintegrate(f, lower = -Inf, upper = Inf ), but stil have the error : roundoff error is detected in the extrapolation table